# TensorFlow Estimator create custom metrics in evaluation mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

How to create custom metrics in TensorFlow Estimator? Like MRR, NDCG metrics in information retrieval area.

Actually, the main problem puzzles me is how TensorFlow computes evaluation metrics with `batch`. Does it first compute the mean of a metric (e.g. `accuracy`) in a batch, then automatically compute the mean of the number of batches?

Comment: [The API doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy) seems to answer your question.

```
The accuracy function creates two local variables, total and count that are used to compute the frequency with which predictions matches labels. This frequency is ultimately returned as accuracy: an idempotent operation that simply divides total by count.
```

Comment: Did you actually succeed in building a custom metric that can work with estimators? I'm interested in the MRR metric.